# Adnroid jni, передача пустой строки в String

Tags: java, android, jni

Подскажите, как передавать пустые строки из `jni` в джаву. Для передачи строк есть функция: `NewStringUTF()`, но, если в нее передать пустую строку, то при обращении к этой переменной джава упадет. Что конечно потрясающее и тупо. Сейчас при передаче пустой строки я заменяю ее на " ". Должен признаться, ни в одном другом языке такой фигней не страдал. Мне так и заменять пустые строки пробелом или есть адекватные решения? Дополнительные проверки в джаве, а не пустая ли это строка, я за решение не считаю.

Так же вопрос, можно ли указывать длину строки в `NewStringUTF()`? Функция, определяющая конец строки по нулевому символу это уже даже не прошлый век.

Comment: для начала расскажите, с какой ошибкой и каким стактрейсом "джава упадет"?

Comment: При попытке воспроизвести ошибку она не повторяется. Видно я свалил одну ошибку на другую, а замена пустых строк на пробелы каким-то образом решало проблему.